# warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What is this error all about? I'm running a standard query like so:

```
time_range = (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)


Feed.find(:all, :conditions => ['created_at = ? AND id not in (?)', time_range, [1,2,3]]).count
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What versions of Ruby and Rails?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this problem and the solution was to add "to_date" so that it iterates over the days, like so:

```
time_range = (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date..1.month.ago.end_of_month.to_date)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you are doing `created_at = ?, time_range`, and time_range is not a specific value, and an = expects a specific value. Can't explain exactly the why for that error, but can get you a solution.

Do this instead, I tried it and works great

```
1.9.3-p125 :014 > time_range = (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)
 => Sun, 01 Apr 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Mon, 30 Apr 2012 23:59:59 UTC +00:00 
1.9.3-p125 :015 > Post.where(:created_at => time_range).where('id not in (?)', [1,2,3]).count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-04-30 23:59:59.999999') AND (id not in (1,2,3))
 => 0
```

---

**UPDATE**

Not directly related to the question, but you should place those conditions in scopes with semantic meaning so you would have `Feed.from_last_month` and something like `Feed.not_with_ids([1,2,3])`

And for your query you would do

```
Feed.from_month.not_with_ids([1,2,3]).count
```

---

For explanation about the warning check the @echristopherson comment below

Comment: Is it possible Rails is smart enough to unpack `Range`s when using `:created_at =>`, but not when the `created_at` is part of raw SQL?

Comment: That's the thing, in the first case you let Rails do his magic, in the second way you are explicit saying what to place in the query ;) Let Rails do his magic for your own good.

Comment: The base reason for the warning is that iteration over `Range`s uses `#succ` to reach the next item each time; and starting in Ruby 1.9.2 `Time#succ` was marked as obsolete because a true time really has no discrete successor; the pre-1.9.2 implementation just used the arbitrary convention of dividing time into seconds. This comes into play when unpacking a `Range` into an `Array`, which is what Rails tries to do here.

Comment: @echristopherson, That makes sense, trying the question approach I got a LOT of those warnings in the console, I guess it was because it was trying to create an array of time by seconds, and a month have something like 2592000 seconds, so an array of size 2592000 was being made. Anyway, rails provide a easy way for querying with ranges.